# How do I separate the numbers from an input in order to add them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to have the user input a series of numbers (separated by commas) to receive the total of them.

I have tried (with no luck):

```
values = input("Input some comma seprated numbers: ")
numbersSum = sum(values)
print ("sum of list element is : ", numbersSum)

values = input("Input some comma seprated numbers: ")
list = values.split(",")
sum(list)
print ("The total sum is: ", sum)
```

If the user inputs 5.5,6,5.5 the expected output will be 17.

Comment: a while loop to take input from users first, then a list that would store those input, finally the sum of it.

Comment: The result of the `input` is the `<tuple>` data type, not `<str>` type. You cann't use `string.split()` method on `<tuple>` data type.

Comment: @s3n0 That is not true. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: @BilltheLizard yes, I know, but in the case of the code above is the result just a `<tuple>` ! So, the `string.split()` method does not work there.

Comment: @s3n0 Based on the print statements, the OP appears to be using Python 3.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Would it be safe to update the tags to reflect Python3?

Comment: @Jay Normally I'd wait for the OP to do it, but since `sum` *isn't* working, I think it's safe to assume in this case.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Thanks. I did it. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'm a beginner, so any support means a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `split` the values by comma into a list, you need to convert them from strings to numbers.  You can do that with

```
values = input("Input some comma seprated numbers: ")
lst = values.split(",")
lst = [float(x) for x in lst]
total = sum(lst)
print("The total sum is: ", total)
```

For reference, see [List Comprehensions in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

(Also, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, since that's a function in Python.)

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there.

After splitting, the values will still be strings, so you have to map them to float.

```
values = "5.5,6,5.5" # input("Input some comma seprated numbers: ")
L = list(map(float, values.split(",")))
print ("The total sum is: ", sum(L))
```

Output:

```
The total sum is:  17.0
```

Side note: Please don't name your variables `list` or `sum`, otherwise you will shadow the python built-ins!

Comment: Yup. But in this case, as the user input must be used `raw_input()` which gives a string, instead of the standard `input()` which returns a specific data structure. ////EDIT: Sorry, this is for Python 2.x only :). Python 3.x is a new magic :).

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the inputs to float:

```
numbers = input("Input some comma seprated numbers: ")

result = sum([float(n) for n in numbers.split(',')])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert to numbers before adding them together.

For example, you could convert them all into `float`s:

```
input_str = input("Input some comma seprated numbers: ")

# Option1: without error checking
number_list = [float(s) for s in input_str.split(',')]

# Option2: with error checking, if you are not sure if the user will input only valid numbers
number_list = []
for s in input_str.split(','):
    try:
        n = float(s)
        number_list.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print("The list of valid numbers is:", number_list)
print("The sum of the list is:", sum(number_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what went wrong w\o a sample of the error\output code.

I think the issue is in getting the sum of list (very bad name btw) when it's a list of strings.

please try the following

```
values = input("Input some comma seprated numbers: ")
lst = values.split(",")
lst = [int(curr) for curr in lst]
sum(lst)
print ("The total sum is: ", sum)
```

This code will work when expecting integers, if you want floats then change the list comprehension.

**Try not to name objects with the same name of standard objects such as list,int,str,float etc...**

Answer (score 0):

```
# empty list to store the user inputs
lst = []      

# a loop that will keep taking input until the user wants
while True:
    # ask for the input
    value = input("Input a number: ")
    # append the value to the list
    lst.append(value)
    # if the user wants to exit
    IsExit = input("enter exit to exit")
    if 'exit' in IsExit:
        break

# take the sum of each element (casted to float) in the lst 
print("The sum of the list: {} ".format(sum([float(x) for x in lst])))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Input a number: 5.5
enter exit to exitno
Input a number: 6
enter exit to exitno
Input a number: 5.5
enter exit to exitexit
The sum of the list: 17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use below

```
print('sum of input is :',sum(list(map(float,input('Input some comma separated numbers: ').split(',')))))
```